# Understanding C++ variable number of input parameters to test_function(Test<T>...)

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I have a generic class `Test<T>` and I want to have a function `test_function()` that has a variable number of `Test<T>` object input parameters with `...`. In the function, I want to iterate over all the parameters. The generic type `T` can be different across the parameters. Something like this:

```cpp
template <typename T> class Test {
private:
    T value = (T)0;
    int test = 1;
public:
    Test() = default;
    int get_test() {
        return test;
    }
}

template <typename T> void test_function(const Test<T> tests...) {
    for(auto test : tests) {
        cout << test.get_test() << endl;
    }
}
```

When compiling, I get the errors:

```
error C3520: "T": Parameter pack must be extended in this context
error C3520: "tests": Parameter pack must be extended in this context
error C3312: no callable 'begin' function found for type 'unknown-type'
error C3312: no callable 'end' function found for type 'unknown-type'
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Is it possible to have a counter in the expansion?

EDIT 2: I figured it out with the counter:

```cpp
template <typename ...T> void test_function(const Test<T> ...tests) {
    int i=0;
    ((cout << tests.get_test() << ", counter = " << i++ << endl), ...);
}
```

Comment: Why did you add `...`? This doesn't make seance and is source of your problem.

Comment: *"The generic type `T` can be different across the parameters."* -- and yet, there is only one `T` available when you use `template<typename T>` (instead of, for example, `tamplet<typename ... T>`). Am I misunderstanding, or did you over-limit yourself with your choice of a single template parameter for the function?

Comment: `Test<T>` is not iterable type and you try to iterable over `tests`. I'm guessing that is why you have add `...`, but this doesn't make `tests` iterable either. Looks like you are trying to use feature you do not grasp even on basic level.

Comment: @Marek R I wouln't have asked the question if I was already familiar with that feature. I'm want to learn :)

Comment: I'm just saying you are trying to swim by jumping into deep water. It would be more beneficial for you by start practice in some easier place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple problems here.

First, the correct variadic template function declaration should be:

```
template <typename ...T> void test_function(const Test<T> ...tests)
```

But that won't solve all the problems. The first one is that all the parameters are `const` objects, therefore the class method must also be a const class member:

```
int get_test() const {
```

Finally:

```
for(auto test : tests) {
```

`tests` is not a container that can be range-iterated over, like a vector. It is a parameter pack and needs to be expanded like one:

```
((cout << tests.get_test()), ...);
```

Tested with gcc 11:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T> class Test {
private:
    T value = (T)0;
    int test = 1;
public:
    Test() = default;
    int get_test() const {
        return test;
    }
};

template <typename ...T> void test_function(const Test<T> ...tests) {

    ((cout << tests.get_test()), ...);
}

void foo()
{
    test_function(Test<int>{}, Test<char>{});
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Just one more thing: Is ist possible to have a counter during expansion? I'll add to the original question what I mean to make it clear.

Comment: One question per Stackoverflow question, please.